# PHP MYSQL 'INSERT INTO $table VALUES ......' variable number of fields

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am still learning PHP and MYSQL and trying to make a program to list all tables and data in database (that's done), edit selected row (that's done) and now add new record on selected table. Now the problem is with variable number of fields. Table could be with 3 fields, could be 4 and so on. On my code here $getValue is an array. I am printing it out only for testing. It could look like "Array ( [name] => Tomas [lastName] => Timas )" or "Array ( [stufName] => Phone [stufPrice] => 58 [comments] => My new phone )"
$getTable returns name of a table to insert into.
This has to be a new record on the table, so stufID or nameID or what ever ID will be NULL
How do I use "INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)" if I do not know the number of values?

```
    <?php

include "conf.ini"; //connection to the db

$getValue=$_REQUEST['value'];
$getTable=$_REQUEST['table'];

// test********************
print_r($getValue);
print '<br>';
print $getTable;
// test********************

if (!$_POST['submit']) {
    print 'Please input data';
} else {

    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $getTable VALUES (?????)");
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't insert 4 entries into a table with 3 columns—if doing so MySQL will give you an error. You said, you are already listing all tables, whereat I suppose you are reading the accordant information from the `information_schema` database. If you do so, you also know the number of columns each table has!?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know this is **very dangerous**, so do this only if you're sure there are no potentional attackers!

```
$all_keys = array_keys($getValue);
$getValue = array_map('mysql_real_Escape_string', $getValues);
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $getTable (`".implode('`,`', $all_keys)."`) VALUES ('".(implode(",", $getValue))."')");
```

Comment: This is only my practice program. This will never be live. I will try this. Thank you

Comment: mysql_Real_escape_string should be done separately on each value, and not on all of them together. The way you wrote that won't work.

Comment: @shesek: yes, that's true. Changed it now

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($getValue));
$keys = array_keys($getValue);        
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $getTable (".implode(',', $keys).") VALUES ('".implode('\',\'', $values)."')");
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that `array_keys()` and `array_values()` will return the corresponding elements in the same order.

Comment: @cdhowie, array_keys() and array_values() does always return the elements in the same order.

Comment: The PHP docs don't indicate that the functions order their results in any particular way.

Comment: Dekui Laurynai. Pabandysiu. Dabar tik reikia issiaiskinti ka daro kiekviena komanda :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create an include file to execute the values for $gettables and then it include that where you want $gettables values to be picked up.