# Safe INSERT with a variable number of placeholders

Tags: python, sqlite

With Python's `sqlite3` library, can I have a variable number of place holders in the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?)`
```

where `?` are the place holders, which is safe from an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack?

I want to be able to have a general function (below) that checks number of columns and writes data into a row but it could work for any table with any number of columns.

I looked at:

- [Python Sqlite3: INSERT INTO table VALUE(dictionary goes here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108162/python-sqlite3-insert-into-table-valuedictionary-goes-here) and
- [PHP MYSQL 'INSERT INTO $table VALUES ......' variable number of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296180/php-mysql-insert-into-table-values-variable-number-of-fields)

but I'm still not sure.

```
def rowin(self, TableName, ColumnData=[]):
    # First check number columns in the table TableName to confirm ColumnData=[] fits
    check = "PRAGMA table_info(%s)"%TableName
    conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_file)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(check)
    ColCount = len(c.fetchall())
    # Compare TableName Column count to len(ColumnData)

    if ColCount == len(ColumnData):
        # I want to be have the number of ? = ColCount
        c.executemany('''INSERT INTO {tn} VALUES (?,?)'''.format(tn=TableName), ColumnData)
        conn.commit()

    else:
        print("Input doesn't match number of columns")
```

Comment: ",".join(["?"] * ColCount) will create a string "?,?,?", where the number of ? characters match ColCount. Does this help?

Comment: Yes that does.  Thank you! I ended up doing   a for loop first:                                 for cols in range(1,len(ColumnData)):
            qmark += ",?"                                                                       followed by:                                                                            c.execute('''INSERT INTO {tn} VALUES ({q})'''.format(tn=TableName, q=qmark),ColumnData)

Answer (score 2):

```
def rowin(self,TableName,ColumnData=[]):
        #first count number columns in the table TableName
        check = "PRAGMA table_info(%s)"%TableName
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database_file)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(check)
        #assing number of columns to ColCount
        ColCount = len(c.fetchall())
        #compare TableName Column count to len(ColumnData)
        qmark = "?"
        #first create a place holder for each value going to each column
        for cols in range(1,len(ColumnData)):
            qmark += ",?"
        #then check that the columns in the table match the incomming number of data
        if ColCount == len(ColumnData):
            #now the qmark should have an equl number of "?" to match each item in the ColumnData list input
            c.execute('''INSERT INTO {tn} VALUES ({q})'''.format(tn=TableName, q=qmark),ColumnData)
            conn.commit()
            print "Database updated"
        else:
            print "input doesnt match number of columns"
```